# Pythonic way for `return (value == 'ok') ? 'ok' : 'nok' `

Tags: python, python-2.7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ternary conditional operator in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/ternary-conditional-operator-in-python)

I have this problem and have no idea to ask google for this:

`(value == 'ok') ? 'ok' : 'not ok'`

I mean that grammar with:

```
(expression) ? (return if <expresion> is true) : (return this value if <expresion> is false
```

Comment: As a note, this is called a 'ternary operator'.

Comment: In C, this is known as the "Ternary operator", Googling `python ternary operator` will point you where you want to go.

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/ternary-conditional-operator-in-python) question. Googling "Python ternary operator" brings you right to it.

Comment: I presume the downvote was from someone who thought this was a trivial answer to find, but it's actually quite hard to find if you don't know the term to look for. +1

Comment: @mgilson as i wrote: I don't have idea how to ask google for it.. I didn't know the name of this grammar

Comment: @WBAR --For what its worth, I'm with Lattyware, I don't agree with the downvote(s) either ...

Comment: It may be more idiomatic for your method to return `True` or `False`.

Comment: I'm polish, so I don't know every english term.. I didn't know the name of it in my own language :) (always self learning programming languages via tutorials and reverse engineering)

Comment: You may also want to return *something* or `None` if the *something* cannot be found. The `None` is the special object for such purpose. If the function ends with `return` without any argument, or if the function simply runs out of the body (no `return` command), it behaves to the caller as if `return None` was executed.

Comment: You could search for "python question mark operator" which gives the desired result.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Easy peasy:

```
'String ok' if value == 'ok' else 'String nok'
```

It's a [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions).

Comment: Also masquerades as a ternary expression.

Comment: Although "conditional expression" is a much better name for it. Even in C "ternary operator" is a pretty stupid name; it's like calling `+` "binary operator".

Answer (score 13):

How about this case:

```
{True: 'String ok', False: 'String nok'}[value == 'ok']
```

*Do not take seriously :)

Comment: This was similar to the old way of doing it before they added the `if else` syntax. But I used to see it with a tuple since a bool will eval to 0 or 1:  `('NOT OK', 'OK')[value=="ok"]
`

Comment: @jdi that is still the prevalent practice in (gasp) *code golf*